# how to set animation for element on scroll (using framer motion)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, framer-motion

I'm working on next.js project. I want the element of the page to be shown with animation using framer motion when I scroll to it.

```
import { motion,useScroll,useInView } from 'framer-motion'
const fadeInUp={
  start:{
    opacity: 0,
   
     translateX:0,
     ranslateY:100,
     ranslateZ:0
  },
  end:{
   
    opacity:1,
    ranslateZ:0
  }
}


return (
<>
//the element below should be shown using motion
 <motion.div transition={{ delay: 0.4 }} initial={fadeInUp.start} whileInView={fadeInUp.end}  >
            <div
              className="hover-up-5 flex w-1/2 lg:w-auto py-4 wow"
              // data-wow-delay=".4s"
            >
              <div
                className="flex justify-center items-center bg-colorGray-50 text-color-500 rounded-xl h-12 w-12 sm:h-20 sm:w-20"
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-8 h-8"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M7 12l3-3 3 3 4-4M8 21l4-4 4 4M3 4h18M4 4h16v12a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V4z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div className="sm:py-2 ml-2 sm:ml-6">
              <CounterSpan unit='k' endNumber={56}/>
                <p className="text-xs sm:text-base text-colorGray-400">
                  Completed Projects
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
</motion.div>
</>
)
```

Everything looks perfect and animation is running. The problem is whenever I scroll to the element, it is shown with animation. But I want it to use animation, only once (first time of scrolling).

When I tried to add `viewport={{ once: true }}` , The animation never runs!